# Help me identify this curved font please

Tags: font-identification

I've ran the design through multiple font identifying websites and adobe font, but because of the circle design, none can identify it. I'm looking for the font that borders this image.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text around the circle seems to be Impact.

[image]

The text in the middle seems to be Futura Extra Bold, or some similar flavour of Futura. There are quite a few.

[image]